# WinRT XAML Toolkit Charting: Hide legend without clipping?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm using the WinRT XAML Toolkit v1.6.1.3.  I have a very small graph that fits on a GridView tile and the legend takes up room that I'd rather give to the graph:

[image: Line graph with legend]

Setting the `LegendStyle`'s `Visibility` to `Collapsed` doesn't do anything.

I have read that people have had success with just setting the `LegendStyle`'s `Width` to `0`.  However, when I do that, I get weird clipping issues with the right and bottom axes:

[image: Line graph without legend]

Does anyone know how of a way to hide the legend without clipping the axes?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it seems that the clipping is due to the weird axis setup I have (I'd like to have one Y axis on the left for the first two series and a second Y axis on the right for the third series), not hiding the legend. Adding a `LegendStyle` with `Width` set to `0` works great for hiding the legend. I'll post another question for the axes.